# For loop instantiates arrays elements to an object, but I have to manually instantiate anyway?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I have an array:

```
Cell[][] grid = new Cell[5][20];

for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++)
    {
        grid[i][j] = new Cell();
    }
}
```

So from my understanding, each element of the array will be made into a new Cell object. That's what I want, but when I try to access a specific element/cell, I get a NULL pointer error.

```
grid[0][1].cellState = 5;    //THIS MAKES AN ERROR!! //
```

To get it to work, I have to instantiate it manually as so:

```
grid[0][1] = new Cell();
grid[0][1].cellState = 5;
```

I just don't understand, isn't the for loop doing this for me? After it's loop at some point, ***i*** and ***j*** will at one point be equal to ***0 1***, so isn't that basically the same as doing 0,1 = new Cell() ???

Thank you for any help, I'm really new to programming.

**EDIT:**

I've figured it out and I'm an idiot, honestly just a stupid mistake that has stumped me for hours. I tried to set the cell state inside the for loop (because I'm just testing). So grid[0][1].cellState = 5 would throw an error on the first loop, because it's not created yet. Sorry, I didn't use my brain, thank you guys for the help.

Comment: All the for loop is doing is counting - not creating objects

Comment: Can you post a MVCE? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you sure you are showing all your code?

Comment: Your double for loop looks fine to me. It correctly initializes your Cell matrix, you don't need to instantiate each cell again if you want to access to it

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into an IDE, and it works fine.

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in a debugger. My best guess is that when you try `grid[0][1].cellState = 5`, your `for` loop has not yet run.

Comment: Slim, did you try setting an elements cellState manually? such as grid[0][1] = 5; Because that is all that's giving me an error, I can do grid[i][j].cellState = 5 and it will all work, but in order to set a specific elements cellState, I must instantiate a new object.

Comment: @JackDavison Please, just post a code snipped that produces the error you are talking about. **We cannot reproduce your error**

Comment: You should post your solution as answer not as edit to the post (question). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You create a Cell object for each index couple of your 2D array.
So your code seems to do the job but you don't show **all** the executed code.
So the problem is probably in another place.

With a Cell class :

```
public class Cell {    
    public int cellState;    
}
```

and a TestClass

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cell[][] grid = new Cell[5][20];

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {

            grid[i][j] = new Cell();
        }
    }

    grid[0][1].cellState = 5; 
    System.out.println(grid[0][1].cellState);
}
```

When I execute this code, I get the following output :

> 5

Comment: @JackDavison It shouldn't matter wether you access the cell object in the loop or after that. You probably have a problem with the scope of your array variable. But unless you finally provide us with some code so that we can reproduce your error we cannot really help you.

Answer (score 1):

If attempt to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

           Cell[][] grid = new Cell[5][20];

            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++)
                {

                    grid[i][j] = new Cell();
                }
            }

           System.out.println("is grid[0][1] == null ? "  +( grid[0][1] == null) );
    }

    public static class Cell {

    }
}
```

You'll find that  `grid[0][1] == null` is false, so the problem is not in the initialization loop.

BTW, a more elegant way to initialize an array is:

```
            for (Cell[] element : grid) {

                Arrays.fill(element, new Cell());
            }
```

Comment: I would appropriate comments from the down-voter.